# i have an inventory program, and it wont load my results

Tags: java

i have this inventory program, but i cant get the information to load. I'm pretty new to programming. i think its either the for loop in the load method. or it could be the myinven[I] = new Item(iID); in the load method.

```
public class Inventory {
    int count = 0;
    int max = 4;
    Item[] myinven = new Item[max];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void save() {
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Inventory.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file");
        }
        for (int I = 0; I <= count - 1; I++)
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.println(myinven[I].getID());
                outputStream.println(myinven[I].getname());
                outputStream.println(myinven[I].getdescription());
                outputStream.println(myinven[I].getonhand());
                outputStream.println(myinven[I].getunitprice());
                outputStream.close();
            }
    }

    public void load() {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Inventory.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The File was not found");
        }

        for (int I = 0; I <= count - 1; I++) {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                    myinven[I] = new Item(inputStream.nextInt());
                    myinven[I].setname(inputStream.nextLine());
                    myinven[I].setdescription(inputStream.nextLine());
                    myinven[I].setonhand(inputStream.nextInt());
                    myinven[I].setunitprice(inputStream.nextDouble());
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you posted is a bit too much. Please analyze the problem until you can break it down into a few lines of example code. Add a bunch of `System.out.println` in places that don't behave as you expected or use a debugger. Also explain *"mostly working, but i cant get the information to load"* in a way that people can understand your problem without knowing your code and the intention of it.

Comment: ok i shortened it, and tried to be clearer

Comment: Ok, reasonable length now (hint: don't put `int I;` at the beginning of a method - Java does not need that and it's easier to read if you declare it as close to the point that uses it as possible - also local variables are typically lowercase e.g. `int i`); What I don't know so far is what "i cant get the information to load" actually means. It looks close to okay. I suspect you get a `IllegalStateException` - is that the case?

Comment: no, when i put in info, and exit the program, the user class calls the save method and saves it to a txt file. when i run the program again i call the load method in my user class and it doesnt load the info, so there is something wrong in the load method.

Comment: When you exit the program, then open the text file with an editor, is there the expected content in it?

Comment: yeah there is supposed to be. when i run the program the first time i put in the information and it saves it

Comment: One thing that can cause problems: `inputStream.close();` is inside the loop and you close the input every time you have read one item. That should in theory crash. Move it down behind the `}` (same for `save()`) and see if that helps.